# python regex with multiple separators

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to separate all the images from the following string.

how can I get a list of images that start with "comp1/img_" and are either split by a "," or a ";"

```
      /*jsonp*/jsonresp({"img_set":"comp1/img_23434;comp1/img_3243r43r,comp1/img_o43nfjr;comp1/img_wjfno43,comp1/img_nrejfner;comp1/img_jrenckerjv,comp1/img_23434k;comp1/img_rkfnk4n"},"fknreff\",");
```

so I would end up with a list like...

```
comp1/img_23434
comp1/img_3243r43r
comp1/img_o43nfjr
comp1/img_wjfno43
comp1/img_nrejfner
comp1/img_jrenckerjv
comp1/img_23434k
comp1/img_rkfnk4n
```

any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: post your code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> data = '/*jsonp*/jsonresp({"img_set":"comp1/img_23434;comp1/img_3243r43r,comp1/img_o43nfjr;comp1/img_wjfno43,comp1/img_nrejfner;comp1/img_jrenckerjv,comp1/img_23434k;comp1/img_rkfnk4n"},"fknreff\",");'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'comp1/img_[^;,"]+', data)
['comp1/img_23434', 'comp1/img_3243r43r', 'comp1/img_o43nfjr', 'comp1/img_wjfno43', 'comp1/img_nrejfner', 'comp1/img_jrenckerjv', 'comp1/img_23434k', 'comp1/img_rkfnk4n']
```